# How to make a dynamically change a count of rows in textarea just like on facebbok dialog?

Tags: javascript, jquery, chat, line-breaks

I'm trying to do a conversation window on my website how is it on a Facebook. I done a layout already but I have a problem with a textarea field. On the Facebook is that, the user presses SHIFT + ENTER is creating new line and a count of rows is increase by one max to five lines.  After a five lines/rows is showing a scrollbar. The same thing happens when the user writes a message and a text jumps to a new line, then a count of rows increase by one line. Very interested me an effect increases a rows. I noticed that, the effect occurs when:

1) The user press SHIFT + ENTER,

2) The user writes a message and occurs a break a word,

3) The user holds one character and occurs a break new line

How can I get this effect?

I need something like this:

Below a snippet code I found on stackoverflow:

```
$('textarea','.dialogbox').keypress(function() {
    if($(this).val().length % 10 == 0) {
        $(this).val($(this).val() + '\n');
    }
});
```

Here is my code:

```
$('textarea','.dialog').keyup(function(event) {

    var arrayOfLines = $(this).val().split('\n');
    $.each(arrayOfLines, function(index, item) {
    index++;
    if(index < 6){
    $('textarea','.dialogbox').attr('rows',index).css('overflow','hidden');
    }else{
    $('textarea','.dialogbox').css('overflow-y','scroll');
    }
});
```

My solution look like this but I need 100% of width so that if a user writes a message and his a last character is in textarea, jquery must insert '\n' in textarea so that keyup function can increase rows by one.

```
$('textarea','.dialogbox').keypress(function() {
    if($(this).val().length % 10 == 0) {
        $(this).val($(this).val() + '\n');
    }
}).keyup(function(event) {

    var arrayOfLines = $(this).val().split('\n');
    $.each(arrayOfLines, function(index, item) {
    index++;
    if(index < 6){
    $('textarea','.dialogbox').attr('rows',index).css('overflow','hidden');
    }else{
    $('textarea','.dialogbox').css('overflow-y','scroll');
    }
});
```

I think that I need a modulo. Keypress function check text field. When in textarea field occurs max length in row then must insert '\n'.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, then, here it is. Next time, try yourself before asking for answers.

CSS

```
textarea {
    overflow: scroll; // for scrollbar
}

div {
    margin: 10px 0;
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
    background: rgba(128,128,128, 0.1);
}

div:nth-child(even) {
    background: rgba(0,128,0, 0.1);
}
```

HTML

```
<textarea rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
```

jQuery

```
$('textarea').keydown(function(event) {
    var cont = $(this).val();
    if (event.shiftKey && event.keyCode == 13) {  // if shift+enter

        var div = $("<div></div>").text(cont);
        $(this).before(div);
        $(this).val("");

    }
});
```

### Edit

```
if(index < 6){
   $('textarea','.dialogbox').attr('rows',index).css('overflow','hidden'); //don't see any use
} else {
    $('textarea','.dialogbox').attr('rows',index); // modified here
}
```

Again, your question is really confusing. Please be more clear.

Comment: It does not solve my problem. I updated my question.

Comment: Open your facebook profile and write something to your friend. If you will write string without any Enter or Shift + Enter, you will see that a field increase himself by one row e.t.c. I would like to have the same effect. Now if you understand me?

Comment: yes, but your code works exactly like you want it to. btw, there's brackets missing. hope, that's not the problem.

Comment: I done! I used only css: line-height: 1.6em; min-height: 3.3em; max-height: 8em;  overflow-y: auto; I also used editable div instead textarea. So, default height is just like one line. When I write long a message, height of div increase to five lines and then is show a scrollbar. It's great. Thanks for help!